# Redis lua script doesn't respect automicity in some case

Tags: java, redis, lua, race-condition

I'm trying to have a implement a simple producer-consumer using Java and Redis.
The flow is this: the producer pushes items into Redis. The consumer reads the items from Redis. In order to make the consumer more efficient - it will not read every item alone, but instead will read batch of items. For that, I'm using this flow:

- Producer push the item to a pending set in Redis.
- When the set count exceeds a given threshold, the items are packed into a batch (using JSON) and being saved into a "ready hashmap".
- The consumer reads the ready hashmap and evaluate its content.
- The consumer removes the items it consumed from the hashmap.

As these operations might cause race conditions, I looked into transactional operations. I understood that the best way to achieve it is with Lua, as redis-lua scripting is atomic.

The script I wrote is this:

```
local toJsonList = function(items)
    local jsonList = '[' .. table.concat(items, ', ') .. ']'
    return cjson.encode(jsonList)
end

-- Get the batch size (the threshold)
local batchSize = tonumber(ARGV[1])

-- Add the new item
redis.call('SADD', KEYS[1], ARGV[2])

-- Get the number of pending items in Redis
local currentPendingQueueItems = redis.call('SCARD', KEYS[1])

-- Should we move the items from the pending queue to the ready queue?
if currentPendingQueueItems < batchSize then
    return 1
end

-- Fetch the items stored in the pending queue
local pendingItems = redis.call('SMEMBERS', KEYS[1])

-- Store the items in the ready queue hash map
redis.call('HSET', KEYS[3], cjson.encode(KEYS[4]), toJsonList(pendingItems))

-- Remove the pending queue
redis.call('DEL', KEYS[1])
return 1
```

The execution is like so:

```
$ redis-cli --eval addAndSync.lua "pending-queue-key" "ready-queue-key" "unique-key-for-batch" , $THRESHOLD "item to add"
```

I started by testing it out individually, and it indeed works fine. The ready queue is synced correctly. I even wrote this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

END=$1
for i in $(seq 1 $END);
  do redis-cli --eval syncReadyQueue.lua "pending" "ready" "ready${i}" , "3" "${i}" &
done
```

Which I ran with `END=100` to test some insertions at once.

My issue is, after integrating it with Java, I started to stress test it. When stress testing and few threads fired at the same time to handle the produced content - each of then ran `addAndSync.lua`. I inspected the ready queue after insertion of even only 30 records and noticed that there are duplicates in the ready queue.
That's unexpected to me, as Redis guaranteed that Lua scripts will block any other client call.
My expected behaviour is that every Lua call will block the access to Redis until it will commit its results, and thus the ready queue will have unique items.

I'd love to get any help in understanding what am I missing.
Thanks!!

Comment: Can you extend about "after integrating it with Java"?